# 3d text problem cap or white lines when copy to photoshop

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

when i try to export my 3d text from illustrator to Photoshop , some cap or white line appear on my work

i try to export as PNG or use copy and paste in Photoshop ( smart Object or shape layer )

i use same resolution and dip and try to group it but none of them solve my probelm

[image]

Comment: Those are conflation artefacts caused by rendering a vector image. Probably better to just use Photoshop to do a 3D text extrusion instead.

Comment: that's very weird , cause both of them is Adobe product , illustrator have more option for control and create more advance 3d text

Comment: It has nothing to do with Adobe really.  It's a common problem with all vector image editors, when pieces of a design butt up against each other.